# Matching the row value of a data frame with its corresponding values

Tags: r

The picture below is my data set in R :

[image]

reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(
  time = rep(0.2, 5),
  m1 = c(9,15,2,8,18),
  m2 = c(11,1,13,12,NA),
  m3 = c(16,NA,7,17,NA),
  m4 = c(10,NA,3,4,NA),
  m5 = c(14,NA,6,NA,NA),
  m6 = c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA)
)
```

I want the following output, which is a table displaying each value in the dataset and below the number of the row to which the value belongs:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try reading up on how to ask a question, that can be answered by others: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of dput(<yourData>) or dput(head(<yourData>)) to your question is sufficient. Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images.

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image. No one wants to type it all in again. Instead,  please use `dput` to make a text version of your data and paste it into your question. I notice that you did not bother to take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) I recommend it. I also recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first column, transpose what is left, convert it back to a data frame, set the column names to the original row numbers, stack that and omit NA rows.  Then re-order by values.

```
d <- na.omit(stack(setNames(as.data.frame(t(data[-1])), 1:nrow(data))))
d[order(d$values), ]
```

giving:

```
   values ind
8       1   2
13      2   3
16      3   3
22      4   4
18      5   3
17      6   3
15      7   3
19      8   4
1       9   1
4      10   1
2      11   1
20     12   4
14     13   3
5      14   1
7      15   2
3      16   1
21     17   4
25     18   5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  rownames_to_column("row_id") %>% 
  gather(key, value, -time, -row_id) %>% 
  select(1, 4) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  spread(value, row_id)
```

output is:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 4 1  1  1  4  3  1  2  1  4  5
```